# how to use variable in golang regexp pattern

Tags: regex, go

how do i use variable as a pattern in golang regexp.

```
wordVar := "demo"

rgx := regexp.MustCompile(`\d+\t(\w+)`) // this work

rgx := regexp.MustCompile(`\d+\t( + wordVar + )`) // this failed
```

Comment: Please don't spam the same question. The marked duplicate on the other answer shows how to substitute variable values in a string. If something's not clear, ask that, and don't repeat the same question with even less info.

Comment: How about `regexp.MustCompile(\`\d+\t(\` + wordVar + \`)\`) ` ? You probably should use that one with trusted input only

Comment: @ xarantolus thank you... putting the variable in between the tick mark... solved the variable in the regexp pattern

Comment: @icza... I ask the question wrongly... I suppose this would be a better question... " How to substitute a golang regexp pattern with a variable? "

Comment: @shkhoo I marked your question as a duplicate of your previous one. Your previous question have been marked as a duplicate of another question which answers this. Have you read at at all?